# Redirecting to a controller in SpringMvc

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a class which has multiple controller in it and from one of the controller i want to call another controller which is in different class and when the particular controller is called that controller will create the view.

my codes are
**class one** // **class from which controller will be called**

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/register")
public class PatientController {
@RequestMapping(value="/demo1", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String demo1(){
    System.out.println("Demo1 method.....");
    return "redirect:user/dashboard";
}
}
```

**Class second** // **controller of this class to be called**

```
@Controller
        @RequestMapping("/user")
    public class UserDasboardController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/dashboard", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String get(ModelMap model){

            return "userdashboard";// returning view
        }

    }
```

after the first controller is called gives url as `".../register/user/dashboard"`
however it should give  url as`"..../user/dashboard"`.

please suggest how can I achieve this. 
Or there is any other way of doing same thing.

Comment: return "redirect:/user/dashboard" with slash after `redirect:` . look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584410/redirect-in-spring-mvc

Comment: what a silly mistake. and I was breaking my head for hours, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: don't worry, usual case when you are a beginner : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using redirect for the same controller file we can use this as

```
return "redirect: controllerName"
```

if you want to call the controller of another class you have to call it as using `/` before it so that will be as

```
"redirect:/firstController/yourSubController"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is: MvcUriComponentsBuilder [MvcUriComponentsBuilder docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/MvcUriComponentsBuilder.html)

There are some great methods like: fromMethod(), fromController() and more.
You can receive proper redirection path to another method/controller automatically.

Example - redirect to another controller:

```
final UriComponentsBuilder uriComponents = MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromController(WheredoYouWantToRedirectController.class);
final String path = uriComponents.build().getPath();

return REDIRECT_PREFIX+path;
```

In the same way you may work with redirection to methods.
MvcUriComponentsBuilder helps to reduce errors connected with redirections.

Please check documentation for more info.