# Spring MVC REDIRECTION PAGE

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

It is simple page redirection example.When i click on it's button redirect page, it,s not working.It shows page not found.

final.jsp

```
<body>

    <h2>Redirected Page</h2>

</body>
```

HelloController.java

```
 @Controller 
 public class HelloController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String index(Model m) {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirect() {

    return "redirect:finalPage";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/finalPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String finalPage(Model m) {

    return "final";
}
```

index.jsp

```
<body>
    <h2>Spring Page Redirection</h2>
    <p>Click below button to redirect the result to new page</p>
    <form:form method="GET" action="/finalPage">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Redirect Page"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>  
    </form:form>
</body>
```

web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned redirect string is wrong, try: `"redirect:/finalPage"`

Answer (score 1):

Missed / in redirect:finalpage. It should be something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirect() {

    return "redirect:/finalPage";
}
```

But from where you are calling /redirect ?

Answer (score 0):

Please also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584410/redirect-in-spring-mvc). Basically, you need to have a `UrlBasedViewResolver` subclass in your project and have the final view in there, if it's not in root.