# Ant matcher to "default" / in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, keycloak

How to map security constraint to defult page ? e.g. I'm using Keycloak and i want my app to redirect to Keycloak's login page whenever user tries to achieve my app: `localhost:8080/` <- this must redirect to Keycloak's login page.

I tried the following patterns:

```
1. super.configure(http);
    http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/*").hasRole("ADMIN");

2.super.configure(http);
    http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").hasRole("ADMIN");


3.super.configure(http);
    http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN");

4.super.configure(http);
    http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN");


5.super.configure(http);
    http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("*").hasRole("ADMIN");
```

But none of them works...

Btw when i type `sub-urls` e.g. `localhost:8080/users`, everything works fine and Keycloak's login page occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue with the Spring Security adapter. A workaround is to redirect your user to some other path (e.g. /home.html) when the root path is requested. In a `@Controller`:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
protected String redirect() 
{
    return "redirect:/home.html";
}
```

**See also:**

- [redirect in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584410/redirect-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Thanks, Xtreme Biker!

Comment: Sure! Dude,thanks for your helping, bcz it seems like stack overflow community is not as active as before... Would you mind if i ask you one question not related to the post? Btw i can't upvote yet cuz i don't have 15 point lol

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your points! :)  Here's my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50869055/keycloak-retrieve-all-available-client-sessions