# Keycloak: retrieve all available client sessions

Tags: java, spring, keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm using Keycloak to secure my Spring app (which is registered in Keycloak as `my_app` client). Now I want to retrieve all active sessions of that client. Would be great if I could do it using keycloak-admin-client, because I couldn't figure out how to use Admin Rest API in java...

So far I've tried this:

```
Keycloak keycloak=KeycloakBuilder.builder()
    .serverUrl("http://localhost:8180/auth")
    .realm("master")
    .username("admin")
    .password("admin")
    .clientId("admin-cli")
    .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build()).build();

ClientResource client=keycloak.realm("MY_REALM").clients().get("my_app").getUserSessions(1,100);
```

But it throws 404 error.

Answer (score 3):

`List clientRepresentations=keycloak.realm("MY_REALM").clients().findByClientId("my_app"); ClientRepresentation representation=clientRepresentations.get(0);
ClientResource resource=keycloak.realm("MY_REALM").clients().get(representation.getId());`

did the trick.

And this retrieves all active sessions in client:

`List sessions=resource.getUserSessions(0,1000);`