# Spring redirect from ErrorController

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a number of generic error pages which are used by multiple applications other than the one I have control of. I would like to configure the Spring Boot error controller to do a redirect to one of these pages. Unfortunately it's not working.

Eg.

```
  @Controller  
  public class MyCustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
      Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);

      if (status != null) {
        Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());

        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
          return "redirect:https://www.example.com/error-404";
        }
      }

      return "redirect:https://www.example.com/error-500";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
      return "/error";
    }
  }
```

If for example I purposefully mistype a URL I can see the response has the Location header with the 404 URL I am expecting but the browser doesn't actually redirect. Any ideas if it's possible to do a redirect from within a custom ErrorController?

Could this be because I'm trying to test this from localhost, and Strict-Transport-Security is ignoring the response Location header value (which is on a FQDN)?

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
  @Controller  
  public class MyCustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
      Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);

      if (status != null) {
        Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());

        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
          return "redirect:/error-404"; //remove your https://www.example.com
        }
      }

      return "redirect:/error-500";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
      return "/error";
    }
  }
```

** **EDIT** **
change the url mapping and try again:
error-404 -> error/404
error-500 -> error/500

```
@Controller  
  public class MyCustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
      Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);

      if (status != null) {
        Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());

        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
          return "redirect:/error/404"; //remove your https://www.example.com
        }
      }

      return "redirect:/error/500";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
      return "/error";
    }
  }
```

**error/404**

```
@GetMapping("/error/404")
```

**error/500**

```
@GetMapping("/error/500")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding HttpServletResponse to the method param and use it for redirection?

```
HttpServletResponse response;       
response.sendRedirect("https://www.example.com/error-404");
```

Reference [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36423878/1708246)

Comment: same result I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

Add the following properties in `application.proerties` file

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```